# how to specify Wsdl location in maven?

Tags: wsdl, maven-plugin, maven-3, wsdl2java, maven-release-plugin

I have created a multi-module maven archetype which will accept the wsdl as input and generate interface and implementation class.

I have given the wsdl in the META-INF/wsdl/Myservice.wsdl.

But my requirement I need to specify the location of wsdl eg:c:/wsdl/Myservice.wsdl using command line when I am generating the project using the archetype or else need to specify the location in the maven archetype properties itself, So that the archetype must get the wsdl and place it inside META-INF/wsdl/Myservice.wsdl and generate the code.

Guide me, how to do it in maven archetype?

Comment: Are you trying to create an archetype?

Comment: yes creating a archetype......

Comment: Than i assume there is no chance to get something which is outside the current project nor inside and which must be copied into the project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably wont be able to do it.

You may add a propertie, referencing the wsdl url, and then bind the validate phase to an  execution of maven-exec-plugin or maven-antrun-plugin, which will download it for you ... but it is a really bad solution.

**So just prepare structure, your plugin dependencies (like wsdl2java), and let the final user place it under the righ path.**